# Show that measure is trivial

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu(dx,dy)$ be a Borel measure with compact support on $\left\{(x,y) \mid x>0, y>0 \right\}$ and let $\mu(dx,dy)$ satisfy
$$
   \mu(dx,dy) = \lambda^{\alpha} \mu \left( d \frac{x}{\lambda}, d\frac{y}{\lambda} \right), \tag{1}
$$
for any $\lambda>0$ and for some fixed $\alpha>0$. Is it true that $\mu(dx,dy) \equiv 0$?

If measure is absolutely continuous: $\mu(dx,dy) = a(x,y) dxdy$ then the equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
   a(x,y) = \lambda^{\alpha-2} a \left( \frac{x}{\lambda}, \frac{y}{\lambda} \right).
$$
Now let $\lambda \to \infty$ if $\alpha \leqslant 2$ or $\lambda \to 0$ if $\alpha \geqslant 2$ to obtain $a(x,y) \equiv 0$. So the case of absolutely continuous measures is clear. Then the question is if it is true also for arbitrary Borel measures with compact support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $S\subset\{(x,y),x>0,y>0\}$ a measurable set and let $K$ be the support of $\mu$. Then 
for all $\lambda>0$, we have 
$$\mu(S)=\lambda^\alpha\mu(\alpha^{-1}S)\leqslant \lambda^\alpha\mu(K).$$
Now let $\lambda\to 0$.